A movie about 2 guys keep a man and a woman and the woman's niece captive
This movie I am trying to find is about a couple, and the woman's niece, they're being held captive by two men, they let them in because their vehicle broke down and they needed to use the phone.
I vaguely remember a few scenes,

They shoot the dog.
I think one of the men holding them hostage used to be a patient of the woman (she is a doctor) and he's seeking revenge from her.
One of the men holding the 3 hostage cuts the nieces hair off with an axe.
The niece kills one of the two men by sticking a nail in his ear.
They also have to play twisted games to survive such as taking off clothes in front of each other if they don't answer a question right and flipping to a page in an address book and choose a number and only have one minute to talk.


Welcome to the community. Answering the following questions will help us to respond. Any other plot details? What year did you see it? What was the language? Can you estimate the year and country of production? I hope you enjoy this place as much as I have.

Welcome to Movies & TV! Welcome to Movies & TV! Please try to add anything that may help identification. When was it released? Was it in Color or Black & White? What time period was it showing? What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. You might also want to provide a more descriptive question title

It's not a complete match - but it sounds similar to Funny Games which was a shot-for-shot remake of an Austrian film by the same director
